# Remove third occurrence of pattern from file

Tags: regex

I need to remove more than 2 occurrences of pattern match.

Sample input

```
5006719,9845861877,"2014-10-01 07:53:26","2014-10-01 11:52:15",Expired
5006720,9845885761,"2014-10-01 07:53:11","2014-10-01 11:52:00",Recieved
5006720,9845885761,"2014-10-01 07:53:26","2014-10-01 11:52:15",Expired
5006720,9845885761,"2014-10-01 07:53:27","2014-10-01 11:52:16",Expired
5006720,9845885761,"2014-10-01 10:36:24","2014-10-01 12:35:13",Expired
5006721,9845888313,"2014-10-01 07:53:11","2014-10-01 11:52:01",Expired
5006721,9845888313,"2014-10-01 07:53:27","2014-10-01 11:52:16",Expired
5006722,9848157771,"2014-10-01 07:53:13","2014-10-01 11:52:02",Expired
5006722,9848157771,"2014-10-01 07:53:28","2014-10-01 11:52:17",Expired
5006722,9848157771,"2014-10-01 07:53:29","2014-10-01 11:52:18",Expired
5006723,9848497273,"2014-10-01 07:53:13","2014-10-01 11:52:03",Expired
5006723,9848497273,"2014-10-01 07:53:29","2014-10-01 11:52:18",Expired
5006723,9848497273,"2014-10-01 07:53:30","2014-10-01 11:52:19",Expired
5006723,9848497273,"2014-10-01 10:36:25","2014-10-01 12:35:14",Expired
5006724,9848788789,"2014-10-01 07:53:14","2014-10-01 11:52:04",Expired
```

pattern to match is first column eg 5006719, remove more than two ocurences of this record. result set should be

```
5006719,9845861877,"2014-10-01 07:53:26","2014-10-01 11:52:15",Expired
5006720,9845885761,"2014-10-01 07:53:11","2014-10-01 11:52:00",Recieved
5006720,9845885761,"2014-10-01 07:53:26","2014-10-01 11:52:15",Expired
5006721,9845888313,"2014-10-01 07:53:11","2014-10-01 11:52:01",Expired
5006721,9845888313,"2014-10-01 07:53:27","2014-10-01 11:52:16",Expired
5006722,9848157771,"2014-10-01 07:53:13","2014-10-01 11:52:02",Expired
5006722,9848157771,"2014-10-01 07:53:28","2014-10-01 11:52:17",Expired
5006723,9848497273,"2014-10-01 07:53:13","2014-10-01 11:52:03",Expired
5006723,9848497273,"2014-10-01 07:53:29","2014-10-01 11:52:18",Expired
5006724,9848788789,"2014-10-01 07:53:14","2014-10-01 11:52:04",Expired
```

Single entries should remain single, double entries should remain double, triple entries should be stripped to double. Note: We can't match whole line here, only stating column can be matched.

Comment: You have to show us some sort of effort in solving the problem. StackOverflow isn't a 'code-order' website. [What have you tried?](whathaveyoutried.com) What possible solutions do you think there are? Have you tried looking around for this answer anywhere else?

Comment: @AlexK i was trying to solve the problem in php and expecting the answers from here by shell scripts since question is more related to shell scripting thats why I was not posting my attempts. by the way Problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Not comfortable with shell scripts, so solved the problem in php :

```
<?php
$file='sort.csv'; //file containing data
$fileData=fopen($file,'r');
$last = 0; //variable contains last entry
$count = 0; //count of similar occurences

while($row=fgets($fileData)){  //loop through each record
    $data = explode(",", $row);
    if($data['0'] != $last){
        file_put_contents("f1.csv", $row, FILE_APPEND); //output file
        $count = 0;
    }else{
        if($count == 0){
            file_put_contents("f1.csv", $row, FILE_APPEND); //output file
            $count++;
        }
    }
    $last = $data['0'];
}
```